# How do I display the :after content inline with the parent element?

Tags: css, after-effects

I created an `:after` line below an element. I am trying to figure out how I can place the `content: 'or'` in the middle of the line. Right now I can just get the `content: 'or'` under the background line.

Anyone know how I can accomplish this?

```css
.expanded-info {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#expanded-phone:after {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
  display: block;
  content: 'or';
  height: 3px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<span class="expanded-info" id="expanded-phone">Give us a call</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1) The content and background of the same pseudo-element

1. Try to decrease the `line-height` of the content.
2. You can use any font properties to style your pseudo-elements.
3. You can simplify the `margin` property. `20px auto 20px auto` is equivalent to `20px auto`.

Please check the result. Is it what you want to achieve?

```css
.expanded-info {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#expanded-phone:after {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 20px auto; /* 3. */
  display: block;
  content: 'or';
  height: 3px;
  background: #ccc;
  line-height: 2px; /* 1. */
}
```

```html
<span class="expanded-info" id="expanded-phone">Give us a call</span>
```

### 2) A separate class to design the text as a splitter

I prefer to write text content in HTML, not in CSS. So I like to create special classes for each type of content.

For example: https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/OmZYZL

```css
.on-the-line {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  margin: 18px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.on-the-line:after,
.on-the-line:before {
  border-top: solid 3px grey;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 18px 3px;
  width: 18%;
}
.on-the-line.orange {
  color: orange;
}
.on-the-line.orange:after,
.on-the-line.orange:before { 
  border-color: orange;
}
.on-the-line.dotted:after,
.on-the-line.dotted:before { 
  border-top-style: dotted;
}
```

```html
<div class="on-the-line">or</div>
<div class="on-the-line orange">and</div>
<div class="on-the-line orange dotted">something else</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there is anyway that I can style the content in the before element, that is different than the rest.

Comment: You can apply `color`, `font-family`, `font-weight` and other font properties to pseudo-element.

Comment: @Paul I added another solution for a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks for the additional methods! I wondered how to do that, but didn't want to overstay the help! I appreciate your kindness!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```css
.expanded-info {    
    display: block;
    margin: 8px auto; 
    text-align: center; 
    position: relative;
} 

#expanded-phone:after { 
    width: 40%;     
    margin: 20px auto 20px auto; 
    display: block;
    content: 'or';  
    height: 3px; 
    background: #ccc; 
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:10px
}
```

```html
<span class="expanded-info" id="expanded-phone">Give us a call</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  flex-direction:column;
  gap:30px;
  padding:20px;
}
span{
  width:16px;
  height:16px;
  background:red;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:relative;
  display:grid;
  place-items:center;
  border-left:10px solid #fff;
  border-right:10px solid #fff;
}
span::after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border-bottom:2px dashed red;
  z-index:-1;
}
span:nth-of-type(1)::after{
  border-bottom:2px solid red;
}
span:nth-of-type(2)::after{
  border-bottom:2px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).